# Chromium-Browser ignores --allow-file-access-from-files flag

Tags: linux, file, chromium

### Environment

I am using Chromium `78.0.3904.108` Built on Raspbian running on Raspbian 10 on a Raspberry 3b+.
I am opening up a bundled VueJs app via `file://` protocol directly in the browser. The app files are locally available on the machine. Until now everything works as expected. The app displays and works fine !

### Problem

The website files contain a html `<video>` tag to play mp4 video files, which are locally available as well. However, a console error is telling me **Not allowed to load local resource: file:///home/path/to/the/video/file/abc.mp4**

I am very aware of this issue, it's an inbuilt security feature of the browser. However, the machine will only load content owned by me, so I guess I should be safe ignoring the warning.

### Expected behaviour

By passing `--allow-file-access-from-files` to `chromium-browser` I expected it would disable this security feature. Doesn't work. I tried `--disable-web-security` as well. Same result.

I tested the same vue app bundled into an electron executable and having the electron option "webSecurity" set to `false`, the content is able to play without the warning. However, since the playback performance in electron is notable lower than compared the chromium-browser directly, I was trying to use the browser directly.